# Linear algebra subsets, please help:

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine whether the set of vectors $$S = \{(x, y, z)\ |\ x + yz ≥ 0\}$$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ or not.

I am comfortable with the first step (zero vector) but could someone please assist with showing closure under addition and scalar multiplication? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We $(30,1,1) \in S$.

Is $-(30,1,1) \in S$ ?

Answer (score 0):

No it not a subspace for 2 reasons :

- because $x+yz$ is not a linear expression (it contains a product)
- because an inequality will never generate a subspace : you need an equality for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (fill in the details and state clearly what happens)

$$(-1)\cdot( 2,1,-1)=(-2,-1,1)\notin S$$